# How do I use xplanet?

Tags: 10.10, desktop-background

I tried installing **xplanet** today, but when I run the application, nothing happens.

I had it running some years ago and I remember that maybe I have to convince the ubuntu desktop manager to accept the drawn wallpaper from another application, but don't know how I can set this in Ubuntu now.

Any advice or URLs for me?

Comment: This answer does not work for modern Ubuntu 23.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:**

- xplanet is rather old software. It doesn't work properly when **desktop effects** are enabled. To test this, first disable desktop effects via *System → Appearance*:

If you can't get it to work with desktop effects, but it works without them, consider asking another question about it.

---

### Now, onto the problem:

From xplanet's package description:

> In order to run xplanet, you'll need at least one map file. Some maps are included in the xplanet-images package

- You need to install [[image] **xplanet-images**](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xplanet-images) as well. Click this link to install it.

The images used by xplanet are stored in `~/.xplanet/images/` (where `~` is short-hand for your Home Directory; files and folders that start with a `.` are hidden, you can make Nautilus show them by pressing  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, again that's *Your home directory → .xplanet → images*)

- To see if it worked, type*

  ```
  xplanet -window
  ```

  into a terminal. (I've tested this, but if you get any errors, add them to your - question).
- Now, to show xplanet on your desktop, open* `gconf-editor` and navigate to *Apps → Nautilus → Preferences*:
- There, disable **show_desktop** and start `xplanet` normally. It should now be on your desktop.

I've gone through all this, and it seems to work fine. But, as I said, only without desktop effects (but maybe that's just me).

---

*: to open an application, you can either hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, and type the command there or you can open a Terminal via *Applications → Accessories → Terminal*.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for this detailed explanation. I'm seeing the image on my desktop now.

What do I miss when I disable the desktop effects? I don't really care much about eyecandy, so I think I won't notice the differences anyway.

Comment: Do you have them enabled at the moment _and_ see the image on your desktop?

Comment: your images are dead. I had to remove them.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read [this forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=49463).